# Данные Из JSON file поместить в БД MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, json

```
JSON 
{
"address_id":"132",
"address":"Decebal",
"address2":"Traian",
"district":"1",
"city_id":456,
"postal_code":3443,
"phone":446649,
"location":"Moldova",
"last_update":12.12
}

CODE
import mysql.connector
import json

file = open('C:\\Users\\Администратор\\PycharmProjects\\Myproject\\js.json')
d = file.read()
b = json.loads(d)

db = mysql.connector.connect(user='',
password='',
host='',
port='',
database='')

cur = db.cursor()
# res = cur.fetchall()
query = """
insert into table_address(address_id,address,address2,district,city_id,postal_code,phone,location,last_update)
value(
"""

db.commit()
file.close()
db.close
```

А что делать дальше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего будет воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html).

Гораздо эффективнее вставлять данные блоками - т.е. собрать все записи, которые мы хотим вставить в таблицу и вставить их одним куском, а не по одной строке.

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd                    #  pip install pandas
from sqlalchemy import create_engine   #  pip install sqlalchemy

# MySQL DB connection string
connection_string = 'mysql://user:password@server/dbname'

# создаем "SQL Alchemy connection" объект
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

# пример собранных в один блок (список) записей
data = [
{
"address_id":"132",
"address":"Decebal",
"address2":"Traian",
"district":"1",
"city_id":456,
"postal_code":3443,
"phone":446649,
"location":"Moldova",
"last_update":12.12
},
{
"address_id":"133",
"address":"Deceba2",
"address2":"Traian2",
"district":"2",
"city_id":457,
"postal_code":3444,
"phone":446649,
"location":"Moldova",
"last_update":13.12
}
]

# создаем Pandas DataFrame из записей
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# записываем записи в таблицу
df.to_sql("table_address", engine , index=False, if_exists='append')
```

---

Так выглядят данные в виде Pandas DataFrame:

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   address address2 address_id  city_id district  last_update location   phone  postal_code
0  Decebal   Traian        132      456        1        12.12  Moldova  446649         3443
1  Deceba2  Traian2        133      457        2        13.12  Moldova  446649         3444
```